# css or js anchored image rollover with "glued to background" effect on window resize

Tags: css, image, rollover

i've been trying to create this for days with no 100% working results. i want to make 5 anchored image rollovers (for a nav menu) for my website. i must have gone through a dozen tutorials by now. some of them recommended i use js, others recommended css. all of which have yielded mostly problems. the most prevalent problem is when i make a functional image rollover and i position it using css, it doesn't translate its position proportionally with the rest of the images (which have a "glued to the background" effect) when i resize my browser window. basically i want all images (including the rollovers) to have a "glued to the background" effect.

what i have now is the closest i've gotten to the desired effect. in firefox the rollover works only when the mouse hovers over the top 25% of the image and the "glued to the background" effect doesn't work. in chrome the anchored rollover image works fine, but the "glued to the background" effect also doesn't work. here's the code:

```
#news {
position:relative;
left:180px;
bottom:450px;
width:210px;
height:67px;
}


<div id="news" align="center">
<a href="news.html" 
onmouseover="document.news.src='newsRO.png'" 
onmouseout="document.news.src='news.png'">
<img src="news.png" name="news" width="210px" height="67"/>
</a>
</div>
```

here's a link to a live example: http://www.scissormanmusic.com/index_new2.html
there's clearly a lot of positioning & content development i still need to do with some of the other elements on the site. but i should be able to get them in the right places once i can get the menu to function properly...i think

please. any insight would be greatly appreciated. thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Any more code to show? Live example?

By guessing: try `display:block` on your anchors